# Error in defaultCluster(cl) when I try to create a function

Tags: r

I try to set up a function that I can reuse and don't need to add a global variable which not often uses. however, the function can't perform as I expect.

Basically, I only use two functions on it, mclapply and parLapply. Both these two functions can't act properly.

Here is the function i try to build

```r
multi_task <- function(func){
   function(...){
     if(.Platform$OS.type == 'windows'){
       cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores())
       clusterExport(cl,c(), envir = environment())
       } else if(.Platform$OS.type == 'unix'){
         cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = "FORK")
         }
     value <- match.fun(func)(..., if("cl" %in% names(as.list(func)))cl = cl)
     return(value)
     stopCluster(cl)
     gc()
   }
 }
```

when I try parLapply
`target <- multi_task('parLapply')(x, Fun)`, I expect that it will create adequate cluster and return the value. rather it shows `Error in defaultCluster(cl) : no cluster 'cl' supplied and none is registered` and when I try mclapply, i get `Error in checkCluster(cl) : not a valid cluster`.

If I just step by step,

```r
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = "FORK")
t <- parLapply(x,Fun)
stopCluster()
```

then nothing wrong would happen. Is there any restriction on making cluster, or it is something related to environment?

Comment: What is `if("cl" %in% names(as.list(func)))` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Also, anything after a `return` is never executed. Use `on.exit` for that part.

Comment: Thank you! I use that code to try whether the function has "cl" parameter. mclapply don't need one but parlapply need one. and seconde though that could be a problem due to the comma with NULL when cl doesn't exist...

Comment: `if` does not work the way you think it works. You need to use it outside of the parameter list.